# ntfsundelete how to get directories back?

Tags: debian, ntfs, ntfs-3g

My distro is as follow

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.3 (stretch)
Release:    9.3
Codename:   stretch
```

Since I install `ntfs-3g` from debian official. It supposed to be [this](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/ntfs-3g)

**Problem:**
I accidentally `rm /my/2tb_usb_hdd` yesterday. 
It is entire disk. Therefore it has high chance that different directory will has the same filename.
Since I had tried `ntfsundelete /dev/sda3 -u -i 16-28842`

Where 
16 is first `inode` when I use `ntfsundelete /dev/sda3`
28842 is last `inode` when I use `ntfsundelete /dev/sda3`

**Question:**
What will happen when `ntfsundelete` found the same filename?

1. How to get directory structures back? If not got to next one
2. Rename the next one to be an identical one
3. Overwrite the undeleted one?
4. How can I estimate the `undeleted` harddisk size? Because 2TB is the biggest one I have. And the others in my home is not 2TB, but I am not sure that it will carry all the outputs.

PS. I can not tag `ntfsundelete` nor `ntfs-3g`

Comment: I'd rather would try to recover the NTFS stuff with a Windows as I guess there are more and better tools out there for Windows for this job.

Comment: @Thomas Oh yeah! Thank you for your response. I normally works on GNU/Linux Debian and OSX. M$ is for gaming. That's why I was totally forgot this.

Comment: @Thomas, not necessarily. Sarit, have you already given RecuperaBit a try? Disclaimer: I am the author.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto Sounds Cool! Let me finish routine job and try with new shinny harddisk :D

Comment: Using TestDisk, click through device and type to Advanced.. in partition selection, pay attention to the bottom for Undelete. Then select a different drive to save to. I believe its possible to write a script using fls from TestDisk to recover from a single directory if that is needed or when the TD single selection is tedious.. see this answer here: unix.stackexchange.com/a/390174/346155